# How to insert documents and linked document in one request in Reactive programming

Tags: mongodb, reactive

I am starting to work on Reactive programming plugged on a Mongo database.

I am using org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.ReactiveMongoRepository as database interfaces.

I have defined two entities (TeamGroup and Team), the TeamGroup owns a list of Teams (link via a DBRef annotation. (below an overview of the definition)

```
@Document("TeamCategory")
public class TeamGroup {
    @Id
    protected String id;    
    @DBRef
    private List<Team> teams;
}
@Document(“Team")
public class Team {
    @Id
    protected String id;
}
```

The point is that I would like through a single request to insert a new TeamCategory in the database and of course prior to that insert all new Team entities.

I don't know if it is possible? if so I don't know how to proceed, I made several attempts but I am blocked with List of Mono of Team.

Has anyone faced this situation? or knows how to proceed?

Thanks for your help

Edit:
My last code attempt is

```
    public Mono<ServerResponse> createTeamCategory(ServerRequest request) {
        Mono<TeamGroup> z = request.bodyToMono(TeamGroup.class).map( cat -> {
                    return Flux.fromIterable(cat.getTeams())
                            .flatMap(t -> teamRepo.save(t))
                            .collectList()
                            .map(l -> {
                                cat.setTeams(l);
                                return cat;
                            });
                })
                .map(TeamGroup.class::cast);

        return ServerResponse.ok().body(teamGroupRepo.insert(z).next(), TeamGroup.class);
    }
```

and I have as error 
Cannot cast reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable to com.xxx.xyz.zzz.TeamGroup

which I understand as I had to cast explicitly

Answer (score 0):

I went to another solution

```
    public Mono<ServerResponse> createTeamCategory(ServerRequest request) {
        Mono<TeamGroup> insertedTeamGroup = request.bodyToMono(TeamGroup.class)
                .map(teamGroup -> {
                    Mono<TeamGroup> teamGroup1 = Mono.just(teamGroup);
                    Flux<Team> teams  = Flux.fromIterable(teamGroup.getTeams());
                    return Mono.zip(
                            teamGroup1, 
                            teams.flatMap(teamRepo::insert).collectList(), 
                            (tg, ts) -> {
                                tg.setTeams(ts);
                                return tg;})
                            .map(t -> t);
                }).
                flatMap(t -> t)
                .map(teamGroupRepo::insert)
                .flatMap(t -> t);
            return ServerResponse.ok().body(insertedTeamGroup, TeamGroup.class);
    }
```

Damned I feel stupid. I had forgotten I could emit the incoming request

I would be happy if someone else has a more elegant solution :)